# authentication failed due to: In setOptions: Unable to fetch metadata

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, passport.js, adal

I am using Node.js with Passport.js Azure AD to authenticate. I can run in localhost without issue, however when i run behind corporate proxy, i get issue with either connection timeout or econnrefused (when vpn on). To avoid this i tried to add proxy agent and now i am able to send request to azure but i am getting this 
:authentication failed due to: In setOptions: Unable to fetch metadata